# How to index pages that are automatically created in a database

Tags: indexing, seo, google-index

I have http://gamingsoup.com/ . When i try to create a xml site map, all my automatic news pages such as http://gamingsoup.com/news/4275 are not indexed when google crawls my site or when i create a xml site map.

Any help, resources, or tips would be appreciated!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't know nor care that your content is stored in a database. It only sees the content that is served when it requests a URL. If Google is not indexing your site it could be for various reasons including the site/pages are new, poor quality content, thin content, spammy backlinks, etc. You need to create a Google Webmasters Tools account and look for any messages from Google in there. If there are none you need to be patient and give Google time to index your site and/or improve your site's content.